# Publish Word document as web page via OneDrive for Business

Tags: microsoft-word, html, onedrive, sharepoint, microsoft-onedrive

I need to share a Word document (named MyPage.docx) with tables and images via OneDrive Business as a web page with colleagues. The Word document is updated regularly.

When I save the Word document as "Web Page" or "Web Page, Filtered" as MyPage.html file from Word, it displays perfectly fine when opened locally in any browser.

However, when opening the same MyPage.html file from my OneDrive for Business (in a browser, not from Windows Explorer), all images of the document are not displayed, and the broken image icon is displayed instead:

[image: HTML broken image icon]

What is the reason that the images are not displayed?

For example, the HTML code for the images in the original MyPage.html as saved from Word is:

```
<img width="211" height="145" id="Image 1" src="MyPage-Files/image001.png">
```

If MyPage.html is displayed via OneDrive in a browser, then the corresponding code is as follows:

```
<img width=211 height=145 id="Image 1" src="MyPage-Files/image001.png">
```

Comment: When you edit the HTML file, what is the source address shown for the images? That should give you a hint

Comment: Try saving as Single File Web Page instead. This produces a file that browsers can display and that includes within the file all of the needed images.

Comment: @YisroelTech: I answered your question by editing my OP. Please have a look above.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg: A Single File Web Page (MyPage.mht) is not shown at all. Instead, I get the message "Looks like this file doesn't have a preview we can show you -- Open -- Download" (both Open and Download lead to the file being downloaded).
https://i.imgur.com/j7pyIiS.png

Comment: @SteveRindsberg even with a Single File Web Page the images are still not actually stored inside the file, and if you transfer the .mht to a new device it will not show the images.

Comment: @David.P can you share a bit more of what you're trying to accomplish here? Why not share it as a Word document (with View only access) to them?

Comment: @YisroelTech, it definitely needs to be a web page in this case.

Comment: But isn't a shared Word document (shared through OneDrive or Word Online) "a web page"? And even a .html file, were are they going to see it, opening a one drive shared link of a html file doesn't show the preview, it shows the source code of the html

Comment: That happens on private OneDrives. OneDrive for Business shows the HTML page, only the images are missing.

Comment: @David.P but I'm afraid that that's not possible, save as webpage will never include the pictures inside the actual .html file, so it needs to know where to load the images from. So instead, you should try to see what you may be able to do to fit your use case.

Comment: Of course it doesn't contain the images.

Comment: @YisroelTech It's possible that Word's making improperly formatted MHT files, but the whole point of making them is that they do include pictures and other resources that would ordinarily be stored externally to a plain HTML file.  viz https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML

Comment: I checked again and the image is indeed included (BASE64 encoded) in the .mht file, but my browsers (Edge, Chrome, and Opera) didn't seem to support it. I then tried with IE Mode and it did show correctly. So it seems like this standard doesn't have good support in modern browsers.